# Terminology for parts of monomial.

Tags: terminology

Examples of monomials for this question.

$x,x_1,x^2,xy,x_1^2x_2^3,x^2y^3,2xy$

The terminology I currently know.

**Coefficient** - A single positive integer at the start of the monomial. This has a coefficient of 5.

$5x^3$

**Degree** - The sum of all the exponents for a monomial. This has a degree of 4.

$xy^2z$

**Literal** - The part of the monomial less the coefficient. The has a literal of $xy^2z$.

$3xy^2z$

**Variable** - The single case lower case letters. This has two variables $x$ and $y$.

$2x_3^5y^3$

**Index** - The single subscript of a variable. This has the index of $3$.

$2x_3^5$

---

Since the terminology may change based on context, the context of this is [cycle index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_index#Example) and working with [Pólya enumeration theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_enumeration_theorem).

The reason for names of such specific parts is for use with programming code.

---

The parts for which a name (terminology) is sought.

1. What is the terminology when a single variable is combined with an index?

E.g.

$x_1$

2. What is the terminology when a single variable is combined with an index and an exponent?

E.g.

$x_1^2$

3. If a variable letter with an index is also called a variable, then I am seeking a more specific name for the letter.

I need names that are unambiguous or that can not have multiple meanings.

Comment: Here $x$ and $x_3$ seem to be both variables and $x_3^2$ is a power of a variable.

Comment: Indices are usually not perceived by mathematicians as objects. I would consider $x_1$ and $x_2$ as completely different variables, with no more in common than $y$ and $z$.

Comment: @Wuestenfux Thanks. That is along a different line of thought I am thinking that the entire group of the letter, index, and power is a variable, and the parts would have terminology like *variable name*, *variable index* and *variable power*.

Comment: @CaptainLama Yes I agree. In my code the *name*, *index* and *power* are part of a tuple and in your example they would both be in separate tuples.

Comment: In more searching found [this](https://www.mathplanet.com/education/pre-algebra/discover-fractions-and-factors/powers-and-exponents) So what I refer to as variable name there is called *base* and a name for a base with an exponent is called *power*.

Answer (score 1):

My gut feeling would be to say that a scalar *variable* is a combination of a variable *name* with an optional *index*.

```
variable = name + index
```

This doesn't fit a picture where you consider the whole *variable* as a vector, and then use the *index* as a means to extract a *component*. With that you'd have

```
component = variable + index
```

To differentiate the two cases you could explicitly include distinguishing typing information in your names and reach something less ambiguous like

```
scalar variable = vector + index
```

Combine that with an exponent and the best term that I can think of would be *“factor”*.

```
factor = scalar variable + exponent
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't include the details of my code as I didn't want to sway possible answers. In my code, which is Prolog, the group of a variable name, index and power is in a functor, *v(Name,Index,Power)* and a list of these form with a coefficient form a monomial, E.g. `m(1,[v(x,1,1),v(y,1,2)])`. As the code has to access the specific parts at times, I would prefer meaningful names.

Comment: *factor* is a descriptive name (terminology) I have not considered for this. I will give it a test drive.

Comment: I took *factor* for a test drive and it just seems to bring up more thoughts of what it means than it eliminates, in other words *factor* has so many other [meanings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor) that it's many definitions may be confusing to those that read the code. On the other hand as I am not a mathematician, the word is correct and I am just not comfortable with it.